# Failure to Push Docker Image to ECR w/ Docker Go SDK

Tags: go

I'm using the docker client SDK for Go and I'm running to an issue with pushing images to my AWS ECR.

Here is the gist of my func

```
import (
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    dockerclient "github.com/docker/docker/client"
)
func doPush(target string) {
    envCli, err := dockerclient.NewEnvClient()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    rc, err := envCli.ImagePush(
        context.Background(),
        target,
        types.ImagePushOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rc.Close()
}
```

My image is tagged something like [regid].dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo:latest but I get the following error:

> invalid reference format

If I remove the [:tag] from the image name, it works until I get a

> Error response from daemon: Bad parameters and missing X-Registry-Auth: EOF

Comment: nothing weird in [regid] I guess?

Comment: @RickyA no, just a normal 12 digital ID.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and I solved it giving an arbitrary RegistryAuth to the docker push option.

So the following code works :

```
closer, err = dockerClient.ImagePush(context.Background(), privateTagName,
                                     types.ImagePushOptions{
                    All: true,
                    RegistryAuth:"123",
                })
if err != nil{
  panic(err)
}
io.Copy(os.Stdout, closer)
closer.Close()
```

I read in [this post](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10983) that giving any value to RegistryAuth could work.